# How to run a Django/python script file in HTML, upon a button click?

Tags: python, django

I've a simple .py file consisting of the following code

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'mail1@gmail.com', ['mail2@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Running the file in console works perfectly and I'm able to receive emails however I'm not sure how the script can be run upon a HTML button click. Could someone please give me any pointers? Do I've to do anything with the manage.py file as well? I'm new to this, please help.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a very simple task using Django, so I assume you don't have much experience with it. Simply put your action into a view and trigger it with posting a form. Structure would be roughly like this

```
views.py:
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View

class SendMailView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'mail1@gmail.com', ['mail2@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
        return HttpResponse()

template snippet:
<form action="{% url 'your_view_name %}" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Email">
</form>
```

Of course you can also add a little javascript and send the form via AJAX. Also, you would probably require the fields to be entered by the user and then submitted via the form, so you need to add that to your view. Have a look at the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#building-a-form-in-django) for the forms and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/) for the views.